# Curl call to python translation in postman

Tags: python-requests, postman

I have a success Post call to an api via postman, but when I generate the code snippet for the curl call , payload section throwing an error

**The working curl call**

```
curl --location --request POST 'url_to_be_used' \
--header 'Authorization: Token [QWS-T]eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9' \
--form 'payload={
"data": {
"Service_Type": "Tele-Consultation",
"CSR_Partner_Logo": [["", "", "", ""], []],
"Service_Count": "500+",
"Name": "name_to_be_given"
}
}'
```

**Code snippet generated as below**

```
import requests

url = "url_to_be_used"

payload = {'payload': '{
"data": {
"Service_Type": "Tele-Consultation",
"CSR_Partner_Logo": [["", "", "", ""], []],
"Service_Count": "500+",
"Name": "name_to_be_given"
}
}'}
files = [

]
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Token [QWS-T]eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

python throws error as SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal  for the payload which is because of the single quotes i am guessing. When i remove the single code to make it syntax error free , the final post call throws "invalid payload" error. Please guide how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation payload expects dictionary:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

so try:

```
import requests

url = "url_to_be_used"

payload={
"data": {
"Service_Type": "Tele-Consultation",
"CSR_Partner_Logo": [["", "", "", ""], []],
"Service_Count": "500+",
"Name": "name_to_be_given"
}
}
files=[

]
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Token [QWS-T]eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Can you also try with three single quotes

```
import requests

url = "url_to_be_used"

payload={'payload': '''{
"data": {
"Service_Type": "Tele-Consultation",
"CSR_Partner_Logo": [["", "", "", ""], []],
"Service_Count": "500+",
"Name": "name_to_be_given"
}
}'''}
files=[

]
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Token [QWS-T]eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: three single quotes worked :) , can you explain me why it worked ?

Comment: @jyitiska 3 single quote or 3 double quotes represents multi line string . As your pay load is represented as multi line if you use single single quotes then compiler expects it to end with in the same line

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign thank you